# How to delete ruby logs (queries) on webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How to delete this log `[#<...>]` from my webpage?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr3Of.png

My example view:

```
= @categories.each do |category|
    %h2.text-primary= link_to category.title, category
    %p= category.descprition
```

Comment: Post your view file that is rendered when this is appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `=` to `-` on the first line:

```
- @categories.each do |category|
    %h2.text-primary= link_to category.title, category
    %p= category.descprition
```